# How can I skip Solr errors when using solr.UpdateRequestHandler to upload a CSV?

Tags: csv, solr

My solrconfig.xml looks like this:

```
 <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
           <str name="stream.contentType">text/csv</str>
           <str name="update.chain">dateConverter</str>
        </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="dateConverter">
    <processor class="custom.DateConverter" />
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

If there is an error e.g. a number field contains letters I want Solr to skip that record and continue. Currently it fails and none get imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solr 6.1, this will be possible with [TolerantUpdateProcessorFactory](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-445)

In a meanwhile, the only options are doing some sort of document pre-processing to explicitly try to transform error into empty or non-error field, using an one of transforming [UpdateRequestProcessors](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/).